# cambiar asteriscos por puntos en jpasswordfield java

Tags: java, netbeans

El asunto es que no quiero que salgan *

[image: Imagen de actual]

Quiero que salga así, con puntos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo lo hago?
uso netbeans

Comment: Estás usando SWING? Que tipo de componente estás utilizando para capturar la contraseña?

Comment: Dale un ojo a [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359824/replacing-the-password-character-to-dot-in-jpasswordfield)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tienes que modificar la propiedad echoChar, por lo tanto asumiendo que utilizas netbeans puedes guiarte con la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso que necesites hacerlo directamente con código deberás de agregar lo siguiente:

```
jPasswordField.setEchoChar('@ aqui el carácter que deseas utilizar');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias  utilice este  _metodo jpassword.setEchoChar('\u2022');_

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar:

```
myPasswordField.setEchoChar('\u25cf')
```

Comment: A mí el caracter `\u25cf` me da un asterisco. Que raro!

Comment: Colocas en esa propiedad ' \u25cf '